# How to delete pictures fully from within an album

Tags: iphoto

I am using iPhoto 11 and need to sort out and tidy up my library. Currently it has 17,500 photos and I really need to get rid of all the unwanted items.

I realise that there is a distinction between deleting from an album and deleting from the library (The former does not actually remove the file, just the entry in the album).

However, with so many pictures I really need to do this in a more structured way than just trawling through the 17.5k pictures in the library. I would really like to be able to go through my albums one at a time and remove fully any unwanted pics.

When I right-click on a picture in an album there is a 'Remove from album' option. Fine, that works as expected. But there is also a 'Trash' option which seems to do nothing. If I click on 'Trash' from within an album, the picture is NOT placed in Trash and if I search for it in the main library, it is still there.

Surely 'Trash' should do what it says?

Is there some way of selecting a picture in an album and getting rid completely. Forever. Totally. Absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a way (Command + Option + Delete). But in this version of iPhoto, it appears to have been disabled. No idea why -- it was very useful, for exactly the reason you describe.